# Expression Engine Core (Free Version) Templates

Tags: ee2, templates

I downloaded Expression Engine Core, the free version of EE.

Does this version save templates as files or only in the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save templates as files in Core.
https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/templates_as_files.html